# Issue Connecting to Redis in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, redis, connection, database-connection

I am having trouble connecting the redis on Netbeans. I imported the jar file and added the driver, but I do not know if I have a bad port number to connect to, but it wont let me connect. I keep getting this error message:

Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:redis:Server=127.0.0.1;Port=1521;Password=myPassword; using cdata.jdbc.redis.RedisDriver (System error: Connection refused: connect)

I do not know where I am going wrong. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: use redis-cli, try to connect to your redis to ensure the server is running first

Comment: How do i use redis-cli? I am new to redis. can I do it throught the command prompt? I have windows